# Simple proof of the equivalence between two definitions of étale

Tags: galois-theory, derivations

This question shouldn't be too hard to answer, but I'm looking for the most streamlined approach.

Let $K$ be a field and let $L$ be a finite dimensional field extension of $K$. I am interested in two equivalent definitions:

**Definition 1:** For each commutative ring $k$, and a choice of maps $K \rightarrow k, L \rightarrow k$ with $K \rightarrow L \rightarrow k = K \rightarrow k$, $\text{Der}(L, k) \rightarrow \text{Der}(K, k)$ is an isomorphism.

**Definition 2:** $L \otimes_K \overline{K} \cong \prod_{i = 1}^{[L:K]} \overline{K}$, where $\overline{K}$ is the algebraic closure of $\overline{K}$.

This may be a rather basic question, but my complaint about proofs I have found elsewhere is that they are very indirect or don't generalize well. I suspect there is a simple proof that I can't see.

Comment: In definition 2, all of the "k"s should probably be $K$, and the last $\overline{k}$ should also be $K$.

Comment: It seems like one could reduce to the case where $\overline{K}$ is separably closed using descent.

Comment: One doesn't need descent, or rather one only needs the case of descent that is just linear algebra. A derivation is a solution to a system of linear equations, and the map from derivations of $L$ to derivations of $K$ is a linear map. So checking this is an isomorphism over $k$ for all $k$ is equivalent to checking the case $k= \overline{K}$.

Comment: @WillSawin That makes sense, but I still can't quite see how to finish. Do you see (1) $\implies$ (2)?

Comment: Maybe we use the exact sequence $\text{Der}_K(L, \overline{K}) \rightarrow \text{Der}(L, \overline{K}) \rightarrow \text{Der}(K, \overline{K})$.

Comment: The full exact sequence is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exalcomm

Comment: It is easy to show that $\text{Der}_K(L, \overline{K}) = 0$.